# lag/slowdown when I try to display many images in a listview?

Tags: android, image, sqlite, listview, android-listview

When I have so many images to display in a listview when I flow to the bottom of a picture to another there is a 1 second pause. I save the file path in the sd card in the database sqlite internal adapter and therefore in each element is taken before and after the sqlite database from SD card. How do I not have that annoying lag between an image and another? If I view the image grabbing resources such as (R.drawable.image) this does not bother you, I could make images of sd card reached as to the internal resources to the application? Perhaps accidentally memorize the pictures, I should save them for example in Android / data / com.my.app? (Images except the sd card in pictures folder). How can I improve this?

Comment: "How do I not have that annoying lag between an image and another?" -- use TraceView and `StrictMode` to see where your problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Universal Image Loader for loading the images

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

This will resolve your problem.